# iPad stopped streaming quicktime movie clips

Tags: ios, ipad, safari, quicktime

I wasn't sure where to exactly ask this question, so here seemed most appropriate i guess. Something weird happened, quicktime movieclips suddenly stopped streaming in Safari on my Ipad, if i try to load one in the adres bar now i just get a crossed out video icon. I became aware of this because i tried streaming a video thats in an app i developed and all of a sudden it didn't work anymore whereas it had been working perfectly fine before... So i figured trying streaming them in Safari to see if that would work but well... It didn't. This is one of the files http://www.royniginal.nl/newswall/tiles/bioGrid/video/vid1.mov , can someone confirm maybe whether or not this is streaming on an iPad (in safari), like i said it has been working fine on my Ipad before...

Answer (score 0):

No this does not stream, which suggests it is a codec issue. I had this problem with developing websites. If you have access to this video to change it, the best format is MP4 which is the only safari supported video format according to W3C schools HTML5 section. This should fix the problem.

Comment: Mmm weirdly i have switched the hosting service that hosted those same quicktime files and now they're working again without any issues.

Comment: In MPMoviePlayer that is... which suddenly stopped working and was the cause of my problems, so it must have been an issue with hosting in that regard.